# Use Rails 3.1 Asset Paths in a SCSS Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have the following setup:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

/*
*= require_self
*= require fancybox
*/

/* COLORS.. */
/* MIXINS... */
/* FONT STACKS... */

/* IMPORTS */
@import "reset";
@import "supergrid";
@import "rails";
@import "app";
@import "forms";
@import "layout";
```

In my various partials I'm having a real problem with the asset paths. When inside `application.css.scss` or anything loaded by the manifest, I can use:

```
.example { background-image: image-path("background.png"); }
```

However, when I'm using a partial, such as my `_layout.css.scss` partial, when I try the same thing the background-image property is simply omitted from the compiled file. It seems the SCSS asset helpers are not available inside partials?

Has anyone gotten this to work, am I missing something obvious? Or is it simply impossible to use asset helpers in partials? If so this is a major, MAJOR problem, as my entire app structure depends on SCSS variables and mixins which are shared among the partials.

I know that variables and mixins are not shared across the sprockets manifest, so if partials cannot access the asset helpers then I'm looking at having to concatenate everything into a single scss file, which pretty much defeats the purpose of both Sass and Sprockets.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strange, it should work.. Just few ideas:

1. Are you using up-to-date gems sass-rails and sprockets?
2. Try to rename .css.scss to .scss
3. Try to replace `image-path('background.png')` with `asset-url('background.png', image)` or `image-url('background.png')`
4. Try to remove `require_self` from application.css.scss
5. Try to remove all directives from application.css.scss and import those files with @import

Comment: Turns out I just needed to be using `image-url()` Thanks!

Comment: Can you please check this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807470/why-image-path-is-not-resolved-in-scss